# Using CamelCase names for Universal Analytics events is not working

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to track the following Universal Analytics with Camel Case names:

```
 gtag('event', 'login', {
        eventLabel: 'success',
        nonInteraction: false
      });
```

But it doesn't work with Camel Case naming.

It works only if I rename the parameters and use underscore like this:

```
 gtag('event', 'login', {
        event_label: 'success',
        non_interaction: false
      });
```

Could someone please explain why is that?
I checked the GA doc but couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation [reference#event](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference#event) you will see that the tag for event is

```
gtag('event', 'screen_view', {
  'app_name': 'myAppName',
  'screen_name': 'Home'
});
```

This is how it is intended to work.  By changing the parameter name to  eventLabel you are sending a different parameter name which it does not support.

You cant just change things because you want to use camel case.  You need to use what is supported by the endpoint you are sending data to.